# Why does integer division round down in many scripting languages?

Tags: python, ruby, raku, integer-division

In the languages I have tested, `- (x div y )` is not equal to `-x div y`; I have tested `//` in Python, `/` in Ruby, `div` in Perl 6; [C has a similar behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division).

That behavior is usually according to spec, since `div` is usually defined as [the rounding *down* of the result of the division](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/div.html), however it does not make a lot of sense from the arithmetic point of view, since it makes `div` behave in a different way depending on the sign, and it causes confusion such as [this post on how it is done in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123583/why-is-math-floorx-y-x-y-for-two-evenly-divisible-floats-in-python).

Is there some specific rationale behind this design decision, or is just `div` defined that way from scratch? Apparently [Guido van Rossum  uses a coherency argument](http://python-history.blogspot.com.es/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html) in a blog post that explains how it is done in Python, but you can have coherency also if you choose to round up.

(Inspired by [this question by PMurias in the #perl6 IRC channel](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2018-05-20#i_16185508))

Comment: FWIW, in Python `//` is called floor division. Try this: `.7 // .1`. Note that it doesn't evaluate to an `int`.

Comment: FWIW, in Python you can use double negation to get ceiling division: eg `-(-23 // 10)`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Floating-point operations are defined by IEEE754 with numeric applications in mind and, by default, round to the nearest representable value in a very strictly-defined manner.

Integer operations in computers are *not* defined by general international standards.  The operations granted by languages (especially those of the C family) tend to follow  whatever the underlying computer provides.  Some languages define certain operations more robustly than others, but to avoid excessively difficult or slow implementations on the available (and popular) computers of their time, will choose a definition that follows its behaviour quite closely.

For this reason, integer operations tend to *wrap around* on overflow (for addition, multiplication, and shifting-left), and *round towards negative infinity* when producing an inexact result (for division, and shifting-right).  **Both of these are simple *truncation* at their respective end of the integer** in two's-complement binary arithmetic; the simplest way to handle a corner-case.

Other answers discuss the relationship with the remainder or modulus operator that a language might provide alongside division.  Unfortunately they have it backwards.  **Remainder depends on the definition of division, not the other way around**, while modulus can be defined independently of division - if both arguments happen to be positive and division rounds down, they work out to be the same, so people rarely notice.

Most modern languages provide either a remainder operator or a modulus operator, rarely both.  A library function may provide the other operation for people who care about the difference, which is that remainder retains the sign of the dividend, while modulus retains the sign of the divisor.

Comment: This is an interesting point, also because you refer to modular arithmetics. Do you think the same answer could apply if the question would have been: "Why does integer division **rounds up** in many scripting languages?"

Comment: @iGian Well the fact is that most languages *don't* round up for integer division, for the reason I outlined in my answer.  Usually they either call the CPU's DIV instruction and just accept what it does, or they call a subroutine which implements Euclidean division and normally does the same thing.  A reasonable question might be "why does language X round up (or to nearest, or towards zero) when most other languages don't?" - but you'd have to specify X, and the answer would be specific to that language.

Comment: So, many scripting language round down integer division because the CPU DIV is basically an implementation Euclidean division? ---- I'm getting curious about why it should need to round up. Can you suggest a language X which does it?

Comment: @iGian That's just it, I don't know of one offhand - you were the one to bring it up.  There are several which silently coerce integer operands to floating-point and perform a floating-point division unless you explicitly specify otherwise; eg. BBC BASIC defines `/` as FP div, `DIV` as integer with round-down.  The 6502 didn't even have a DIV instruction, so this is with a subroutine.

Comment: In C and C++ and Java, division truncates towards zero, shift right truncates towards negative infinity.

Comment: How is rounding towards negative infinity _the simplest way to handle a corner-case_? Why not towards zero or positive infinity or next integer?

Comment: @GOTO0 It's right there in my answer: truncation in two's complement arithmetic.  Modern CPUs that have divide instructions generally do that, and so do many software subroutines.  However, one way to implement it in a subroutine is to perform unsigned division on the positive form of the operands, then fix the signs afterwards; that will round towards zero.

Comment: That is not the case: integer division does not involve truncation at all (only integer valued digits are computed in all intermediate steps). Also, on x86 and similar architectures, the integer division instruction **has always [rounded towards zero](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IDIV.html)**.

Comment: @GOTO0: The name of the "toward zero" rounding mode is "truncation".  e.g. the floating point `trunc()` function: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/trunc.  If you think of integer division as mathematical division producing a real number, and then rounding that to an integer, the truncation rounding mode expresses the behaviour.  Of course that's not how it's actually implemented internally.  And BTW, for arithmetic right shifting, toward -Inf is clearly the simplest for 2's complement: you get that from just shifting in copies of the sign bit.

Comment: But this answer has an error; it seems to claim that integer division usually rounds toward -Inf in most languages / ISAs.  That's incorrect for all modern CPU architectures that have a divide instruction, and it's also incorrect for ISO C99 and ISO C++11, which both specify signed integer division rounding semantics exactly (to match what all modern CPUs do).  [Integer division rounding with negatives in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/319880).  Previous revisions left it up to the implementation to pick a behaviour (allowing for more efficiency on HW with different semantics).

Comment: @PeterCordes: Actually "truncation" only describes rounding towards zero in sign-magnitude representations, such as IEEE-754 floating point.  In two's complement representation, truncation is effectively rounding towards negative infinity, and *that* is what you get from the simple expedient of shifting in copies of the sign bit at the most-significant end.  In particular, if 0xFFFF is -1, then 0xFFFE is -2.

Comment: @Chromatix: ah, I see how that terminology makes sense.  But I meant mathematical truncation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation), i.e. truncation in the sense of truncating some places after the decimal (or binary) point, or removing / zeroing the fractional part.  Truncation is a term in mathematics, not just computer science / engineering, with a meaning of round toward zero.  I think keeping the round-toward-zero behaviour regardless of the implementation makes the most sense.  (Even though that means you don't simply truncate the bits of the 2's complement representation.)

Answer (score 46):

Ideally, we would like to have two operations `div` and `mod`, satisfying, for each `b>0`:

1. `(a div b) * b + (a mod b) = a`
2. `0 <= (a mod b) < b`
3. `(-a) div b = -(a div b)`

This is, however, a mathematical impossibility. If all the above were true, we would have

```
1 div 2 = 0
1 mod 2 = 1
```

since this is the unique integer solution to (1) and (2). Hence, we would also have, by (3),

```
0 = -0 = -(1 div 2) = (-1) div 2
```

which, by (1), implies

```
-1 = ((-1) div 2) * 2 + ((-1) mod 2) = 0 * 2 + ((-1) mod 2) = (-1) mod 2
```

making `(-1) mod 2 < 0` which contradicts (2).

Hence, we need to give up some property among (1), (2), and (3).

Some programming languages give up (3), and make `div` round down (Python, Ruby).

In some (rare) cases the language offers multiple division operators. For instance, in Haskell we have `div,mod` satisfying only (1) and (2), similarly to Python, and we also have `quot,rem` satisfying only (1) and (3). The latter pair of operators rounds division *towards zero*, at the price of returning negative remainders, e.g., we have `` (-1) `quot` 2 = 0 `` and `` (-1) `rem` 2 = (-1) ``.

C# also gives up (2), and allows `%` to return a negative remainder. Coherently, integer division rounds towards zero. Java, Scala, Pascal, and C, starting from C99, also adopt this strategy.

Comment: C# gives up (2). The `%` operator in C# is not the "mod" operator. It is the "remainder" operator, and a remainder can be negative.

Comment: @EricLippert: Just out of curiosity: If that's the case, why is the operator's id string `op_Modulus` instead of `op_Remainder`?

Comment: @Heinzi: No good reason that I have ever been able to determine. It is just one more on a very long list of small mistakes that don't really matter.

Answer (score 12):

Because the implication of integer division is that the full answer includes a remainder.

Comment: ... and the remainder must be always positive by definition? Apparently, it's not the case in every language: [in C99 the remainder has the same sign as the dividend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder#In_programming_languages)

Comment: Yes, that is correct and the lower limit o length of comments is driving me mad!

Comment: @jjmerelo In Python, the remainder (either with `%` or `divmod()`) always has the same sign as the divisor. Eg `123 % -10` -> -7

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais it's just a matter of convention, apparently. The [wikipedia entry on modulo operation says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation): *When either a or n is negative, the naive definition breaks down and programming languages differ in how these values are defined.*

Answer (score 12):

[Wikipedia has a great article on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), including history as well as theory.

---

As long as a language satisfies the Euclidean division property that `(a/b) * b + (a%b) == a`, both flooring division and truncating division are coherent and arithmetically sensible.

---

Of course people like to argue that one is obviously correct and the other is obviously wrong, but it has more the character of a holy war than a sensible discussion, and it usually has more to do with the choice of their early preferred language than anything else. They also often tend to argue primarily for their chosen `%`, even though it probably makes more sense to choose `/` first and then just pick the `%` that matches.

- Flooring (like Python):

  - No less an authority than Donald Knuth suggests it.
  - `%` following the sign of the divisor is apparently what about 70% of all students guess
  - The operator is usually read as `mod` or `modulo` rather than `remainder`.
  - "C does it"—which isn't even true.<sup>1</sup>
- Truncating (like C++):

  - Makes integer division more consistent with IEEE float division (in default rounding mode).
  - More CPUs implement it. (May not be true at different times in history.)
  - The operator is read `modulo` rather than `remainder` (even though this actually argues *against* their point).
  - The division property conceptually is more about remainder than modulus.
  - The operator is read `mod` rather than `modulo`, so it should follow Fortran's distinction. (This may sound silly, but may have been the clincher for C99. See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.std.c/hjGK3cx_I-o/_zB17QyViDgJ).)
- "Euclidean" (like Pascal—`/` floors or truncates depending on signs, so `%` is never negative):

  - Niklaus Wirth argued that nobody is ever surprised by positive `mod`.
  - Raymond T. Boute later argued that you can't implement Euclidean division naively with either of the other rules.

A number of languages provide both. Typically—as in Ada, Modula-2, some Lisps, Haskell, and Julia—they use names related to `mod` for the Python-style operator and `rem` for the C++-style operator. But not always—Fortran, for example, calls the same things `modulo` and `mod` (as mentioned above for C99).

---

We don't know why Python, Tcl, Perl, and the other influential scripting languages mostly chose flooring. As noted in the question, Guido van Rossum's answer only explains why he had to choose one of the three consistent answers, not why he picked the one he did.

However, I suspect the influence of C was key. Most scripting languages are (at least initially) implemented in C, and borrow their operator inventory from C. C89's implementation-defined `%` is obviously broken, and not suitable for a "friendly" language like Tcl or Python. And C calls the operator "mod". So they go with modulus, not remainder.

---

<sub>1. Despite what the question says—and many people using it as an argument—C actually *doesn't* have similar behavior to Python and friends. C99 requires truncating division, not flooring. C89 allowed either, and also allowed either version of mod, so there's no guarantee of the division property, and no way to write portable code doing signed integer division. That's just broken.</sub>

Comment: *some Lisps*: Common Lisp defines `mod` and `rem`, see http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mod_r.htm and http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_floorc.htm

Comment: @coredump And some other Lisps use other names. MacLisp only provided one, and Racket does the same today. Scheme provides three (`modulo`, `remainder,` and Wirth-style `mod`). I don't think the answer needs to link to every dialect of every language in the world; saying that "some Lisps" use `mod`/`rem`-style naming seems sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

As Paula said, it is because of the remainder.

The algorithm is founded on [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division).

In Ruby, you can write this rebuilding the dividend with consistency:

```
puts (10/3)*3 + 10%3
#=> 10
```

It works the same in real life. 10 apples and 3 people. Ok you can cut one apple in three, but going outside the set integers.

With negative numbers the consistency is also kept:

```
puts (-10/3)*3 + -10%3 #=> -10
puts (10/(-3))*(-3) + 10%(-3) #=> 10
puts (-10/(-3))*(-3) + -10%(-3) #=> -10
```

The quotient is always round down (down along the negative axis) and the reminder follows:

```
puts (-10/3) #=> -4
puts -10%3 #=> 2

puts (10/(-3)) #=> -4
puts 10%(-3) # => -2

puts (-10/(-3)) #=> 3
puts -10%(-3) #=> -1
```

Comment: So the division and modulo operation must be coherent, that's quite clear. But you can choose rounding up or down  and still keep it coherent as long as those equalities hold.

Comment: @jjmerelo, I agree with you, mathematically you can choose a different rule, where `# 10 / 3 = 4 # 10 % 3 = -2 # 3 * 4 - 2 = 10`. But this can not work in set of natural numbers, where `-2` does not exist.

Comment: @iGian What your answer is missing is that there is more than one way to keep the consistency for negative numbers without changing results for positive numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This answer addresses a sub-part of the question that the other (excellent) answers didn't explicitly address.  You noted:

> you can have coherency also if you choose to round up.

Other answers addressed the choice between rounding down (towards -∞) and truncating (rounding towards 0) but didn't compare rounding up (towards ∞).

<sup>(The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50436534) touches on performance reasons to prefer rounding down on a two's-complement machine, which would also apply in comparison to rounding up.  But there are more important *semantic* reasons to avoid rounding up.)</sup>

This answer directly addresses why rounding up is not a great solution.

#### Rounding up breaks elementary-school expectations

Building on an example from a [previous answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50433683), it's common to informally say something like this:

> If I evenly divide fourteen marbles among three people, each person gets four marbles and there are two marbles left over.

Indeed, this is how many students are first taught division (before being introduced to fractions/decimals).  A student might write `14 ÷ 3 = 4 remainder 2`.  Since this is introduced so early, we'd really like our `div` operator to preserve this property.

Or, put a bit more formally, of the three properties discussed in the [top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50434508), the first one (`(a div b) × b + (a mod b) = a`) is by far the most important.

But rounding up breaks this property.  If `div` rounds up, then `14 div 3` returns `5`.  This means that the equation above simplifies to `15 + (13 mod 4) = 13` – and that's not true for *any* definition of `mod`.  Similarly, the less-formal/elementary-school approach is also out of luck – or at least requires introducing negative marbles: "Each person gets 5 marbles and there are negative one marbles left over".

<sup>(Rounding to the nearest integer also breaks the property when, as in the example above, that means rounding up.)</sup>

Thus, if we want to maintain elementary expectations, we *cannot* round up.  And with rounding up off the table, the [coherency argument](http://python-history.blogspot.com.es/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html) that you linked in the question is sufficient to justify rounding down.